# Spring boot CLI doesn't work on Git Bash on windows

Tags: spring-boot, git-bash

Spring boot CLI refuses to run on Git bash window. I've added it to path in windows and works from cmd. The error in git bash is:

`$ spring
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because when attempting to run the Spring Boot CLI jar the script is using both a malformed file path for JAVA_HOME and for the Classpath. When looking at the bin directory of the spring installation you can see two scripts:

spring 
spring.bat

The spring.bat script is executed when you run from the windows CMD and will work fine, however when running in git bash it will use the **spring** script. This script will attempt to correct the issue by using `cygpath` to ensure that the file paths are in a unix format. It does this only when it determines that it is running in a **Cygwin** environment, but does not make this determination when running from the git bash. As a result the file paths become malformed.

Fortunately there is a hack that can resolve this issue if you are interested. Comment out the `if` statement at line 17 through 19 and the add its contents as a separate line like so:

```
# if $cygwin ; then
#   [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
# fi
[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
```

And again for another `if` statement at line 92:

```
# if $cygwin; then
#   SPRING_HOME=`cygpath --path --mixed "$SPRING_HOME"`
#   CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$CLASSPATH"`
# fi

SPRING_HOME=`cygpath --path --mixed "$SPRING_HOME"`
CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$CLASSPATH"`
```

You will now be able to run the Spring Boot CLI from git bash.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while running the "spring" command in git bash, I found that my spring was installed on D drive(while Java was installed on C drive). When running the "spring" command in git bash on C drive directory, I would get the above error. If I switch the directory to D drive in git bash and run the "spring" command again, it would work.